# Problem with trigger and inserting data in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I got a problem with trigger whem im trying to insert data to table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OGRANICZ
BEFORE INSERT ON BILET
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
counter NUMBER(6);
check NUMBER(6);
BEGIN
SELECT id_seans INTO counter FROM seans WHERE id_seans=:NEW.id_seans AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM data) = 2020;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter FROM BILET B WHERE B.id_seans=:NEW.id_seans;
IF (check = :NEW.id_seans  AND counter >=3) THEN 
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'too many');
ELSIF(check <> :NEW.id_seans AND counter >=2) THEN 
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'too many');
END IF;
END;
```

I have to set limit for my table that i cant add to many values with the same value for id_seans in bilet table. When im adding too many values for first value of id_seans it works. But if im trying to add any value for other id_seans there is error like this

```
ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at "SQL_OXRLEFMPXILAXVNAWVBOUVDFO.OGRANICZ", line 6
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
```

Comment: Line 6 (counting from `declare` is the `count(*)`, which can't throw that error. Line 5 could though, if there is no matching row in `seans`; has that been created by this point? I suspect the `check` bit indicates it hasn't? You're also selecting into `counter` from both queries, you maybe meant the first one to be into `check`; but that should probably also be a count. This approach won't scale though - you're risking a mutating table error, and simultaneous inserts won't be prevented as each session's count will only see uncommitted data.

Comment: The trigger has issue bigger that the no_data_found. The 2nd select will throw an ORA-04091 Mutating table exception. It  selects form the same table fires the trigger. You **cannot** do that. *This is not something for a trigger to resolve but belongs in the app or a procedure issuing the insert*. Further neither the IF nor the ELSIF will evaluate true thus rendering the whole thing pointless. The variable CHECK is used in each but it is not initialized so it is NULL thus making both expressions evaluate to null.

Answer (score 0):

`NO_DATA_FOUND` exception might only raise due to the first SELECT statement, while the second one returns an integer starting from zero for any case. So, it's sufficient to handle that exception for the first one in a such a way that

```
BEGIN
   SELECT id_seans 
     INTO counter 
     FROM seans 
    WHERE id_seans=:new.id_seans 
      AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM data) = 2020;
 EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
END;
```